# full text index microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express docker container

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker, containers

Im using this DOCKER container microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express 
When i run this command:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [schema].[table]([Value]) KEY INDEX PK_PropertyValue WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

Im getting this error:

```
Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.
```

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

For other people looking:

Currently, you have to build the image with fts support yourself.

Here is the official example:

```sh
# mssql-agent-fts-ha-tools
# Maintainers: Microsoft Corporation (twright-msft on GitHub)
# GitRepo: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker

# Base OS layer: Latest Ubuntu LTS
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install prerequistes since it is needed to get repo config for SQL server
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq curl apt-transport-https && \
    # Get official Microsoft repository configuration
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    # Install SQL Server from apt
    apt-get install -y mssql-server && \
    # Install optional packages
    apt-get install -y mssql-server-ha && \
    apt-get install -y mssql-server-fts && \
    # Cleanup the Dockerfile
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

# Run SQL Server process
CMD /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-agent-fts-ha-tools/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

The fulltext search feature is not yet included in the docker image. Check the following discussion for more info: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/27

Comment: Do you know what i can use instead? can i use microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer ? Does it contains full text search?

Comment: The offical image microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer doesn't have full text search either. You'll have to create your own image from the official dockerfile and add in the feature flag.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and made a repo with Dockerfile that creates Windows container for SQL Server with Full Text Search. Answer from avolkmann was for Linux container. This one is for Windows container.

https://github.com/kennethchoe/mssql-server-windows-developer-with-fulltext-search

I used base image for Windows 10 (20H2).